# Can Fiddler2 be used to monitor SOAP requests made in Visual Studio debugging session

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, fiddler

I have a .NET application which makes SOAP web service calls to **a 3rd-party web service**.

While debugging the application in Visual Studio, I would like to monitor the outbound HTTP requests using Fiddler2 or a similar tool?

Is this possible? How can it be done?

**Update 2011.02.09 - the web service is 3rd-party, not localhost.**

Comment: did you solved this issue? I am having same issue...thx

Answer (score 4):

Should be possible. I have been using Fiddler to debug my web service (REST) calls and it shouldn't be different with SOAP.

Note that you will need to use IIS and not the visual studio development server.  Make sure that you use the machine name instead of `localhost` and that fiddler is set to capture all processes.

Comment: You can debug traffic to the VS dev server (see "Cassini" at http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp)

Comment: The web service is not hosted on localhost. Only the web service consumer code is on localhost. I added this clarification to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Fiddler can't intercept traffic through localhost, however [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/archive/2008/01/10/tip-for-using-fiddler-on-localhost.aspx) indicates a workaround to make Fiddler capture localhost traffic.

**EDIT:** To answer your question, yes Fiddler can capture SOAP just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Change the url pointing to your service, replace the word "localhost" with "ipv4.fiddler" and the requests should go through fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your App.config and the response traffic should show in Fiddler.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy bypassonlocal="false" usesystemdefault="true" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after  tag to your web.config , I tried that and it worked

```
 <system.net>

    <defaultProxy
                    enabled = "true"
                    useDefaultCredentials = "true">
      <proxy autoDetect="False" bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="False" />
    </defaultProxy>

  </system.net>
```

you can find this from [this telerik article](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler)